# List iterator find function error in c++

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I have a compilation error: "`no matching function for call to find(std::_List_iterator<Process>, std::_List_iterator<Process>, Process&)`" in my c++ program.

The `mfqueue` class looks like:

```
MFQueue::MFQueue() {
        list<Process> queue;
        vector<int> ran;
        int time_quantum = 0;
        int run_for = 0;
}

MFQueue::MFQueue(int quantum) {
        list<Process> queue;
        vector<int> ran;
        int time_quantum = quantum;
        int run_for = 0;
}
```

---

"Process" is one of my class

```
bool MFQueue::contains(Process p) {
        list<Process>::iterator itr = find(queue.begin(), queue.end(), p);
        return (p == *itr);;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `#include <algorithm>` ... `return std::find(queue.begin(), queue.end(), p) != queue.end();`

Comment: `return (p == *itr);` gives undefined behaviour if the object isn't found; you're not allowed to dereference a past-the-end iterator. You want `return itr != queue.end();` instead.

Comment: You better hope you don't need to use a queue as well. As soon as you `#include <queue>`, your code will break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `#include <algorithm>` to your CPP file.

Comment: Don't forget to fix your other logic errors that have been pointed out: redeclaring `queue` in the constructors and incorrectly checking for a failed find.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload `operator==` for `std::find` algorithm, assume you want to compare id of Process
say:

```
 bool operator==(const Process &lhs, const Process& rhs)
 {
   return lhs.id== rhs.id;
 }
```

now, you can get it working

```
#include <algorithm>
std::list<Process>::iterator itr = std::find(queue.begin(), queue.end(), p);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. the problem is I didn't include <algorithm>

Answer (score 0):

Why are you declaring `list<Process> queue;` in the constructors not using them?